# Disallowing Usage of a flag multiple times

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script called script.py that has two optional arguments (-a, -b) and has a single positional argument that either accepts a file or uses stdin. I want to make it so that a flag/file cannot be used multiple times. Thus, something like this shouldn't be allowed

```
./script.py -a 5 -a 7 test.txt
./script.py -a 5 test1.txt test2.txt
```

Is there a way I can do this? I've been combing through argparse (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) but can't seem to find anything that specifically meets my needs. I thought maybe I could use nargs=1 in the add_argument(..) function and potentially check the length of the list generated. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: With a single positional, the second case isn't allowed.  The first is allowed, but `args.a` will be 7.  Why would the user repeat `-a`?  What's wrong with using the last, and ignoring the first?

Answer (score 0):

Use can create a list out of all values in supplied for a:

```py
parser.add_argument('-a', action='append')
```

For `./script.py -a 5 -a 7 test.txt`,
you get a list `a=[5,7]`

Then, check if the length of this array is greater than 1, and throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any sample code in your question, so we don't know how you're setting up the argument parsing — however when I tried it — guessing what you might have done — it seems to detect if the argument is used multiple times.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app')
parser.prog = 'test_script.py'  # For testing - changes argparse msgs.
parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true", default=False)


print(parser.parse_args(['-a', '5', '-a', '7', 'test.txt']))
```

Result

```
usage: test_script.py [-h] [-a]
test_script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 5 7 test.txt
5 7 test.txt
```